# Calling a jquery function in main page from a separate .js file.

Tags: jquery, function

This is my HTML page:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
function closecontactform(){
alert("closing the form");
};
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="elementname">Click me to call function</p>
</body>
```

This is in the myscripts.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#elementname').click(function() {
alert("click detected");
closecontactform();
}); 
});
```

My actual pages are quite a bit more complicated than this and include a lot of jquery but this is the basic problem showing only the code necessary. I want to be able to call a function from a separate .js file, whereas the function is defined in the main page. In this basic simple version I tried removing the $(document).ready(function()... and in this simple example that helps however I require that line in my more complicated pages since removing it seems to break everything else I have going on.

You'll see the "click detected" gets called, but the "closing the form" does not.

Are you able to give me any pointers?

Thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have a scope problem. You don't need to wrap named function in `$(document).ready()`.

If wrapped within `ready` it's scope is only available within that ready function due to closure within the function.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function doAlert() {
        alert('foo');
    } 
    /* can call function since scope in same parent function*/
    doAlert();
}); 
/* function not in scope, is undefined here*/
doAlert();
```

Refactor so function is globally available and will work if called from anywhere. Will work in both cases below:

```
function doAlert() {
    alert('foo');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    doAlert();
});
doAlert();
```

Further note:

Many people worry that functions using jQuery selectors and methods must be wrapped in `$(document).ready()`. Named functions outside of `ready` can contain all jQuery code...  but... they need to be called after DOM is ready to be sure html exists

Comment: Ok. It was a scope problem like you say, however I don't think I was able to remove my $(document).ready() since my actual function actually contains a number of variables and jquery (and css) that do depend on the html being loaded. So what I did was took all of the code out of my separate .js file and put it inside the same $(document).ready() on my main page. That fixed the problem.

Comment: ok..I tried to explain the jQuery code part...you probably can pull the functions out. You still can only call many of the functions from within `ready` but you can have `ready` in diffeent files access same global functions

Comment: see how I wrapped $(document).ready around calling function that is named outside of `ready`. Function won't execture until it is called..regardless of where you define it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
```

below the `<body>`-tag?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to move your script tags to right above your `</body>` tag.

Secondly that should work above if you just remove the document ready. The problem is you defined your function inside of a closure meaning, it's out of scope. Your function doesn't have to be in a document ready because it will only get fired when the other document ready is fired (meaning the document is ready).

Comment: script at top (head) or bottom (body) will not impact scope problem. Not really relevant to issue here